# Auto validating a page on load (using W3C validator)

Tags: php

I am developing a web site whose HTML can vary quite a lot depending on user inputs (user input on page 1 decides which sections of page 2 are shown, etc).

Naturally, I would like to ensure that the HTML is valid, but there are a lot of permutations.

I was wondering if anyone has a code snippet which I could include (in debug mode) in my standard page footer template which would validate the page. That ought to help me catch a lot during development and unit testing.

The catch is that I am developing using NetBeans and Xampp, so my URL is on `http://localhost` which is not something I can feed to "validate by URL" ...

---

The following will not work on http://localhost

- W3C "validate by URL"
- Web Developer for FireFox
- Total Validator for FireFox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it can't be done, then

Answer (score 0):

If your using Firefox, then try the Web Developer Toolbar. It has validation tools.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/

Comment: Sorry, I already tried that and it won't work.  As stated above my URL is on http://localhost, so W3C says "Sorry, the IP address of localhost is not public. For security reasons, validating resources located at non-public IP addresses has been disabled in this service. "